# Disable tab bar navigating to root view

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar based application with navigation on each tab bar item.
When i navigate to another view on any tab bar  item and click on on tab bar item,then root view controller on that tab bar item is called. 
Its like PopToRootView .
Can we  disable this situation?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can disable the automatic `popToRootViewController` by implementing the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` method on your view controller:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    if(self.navigationController == viewController) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Thanks to: [Disable action - user taps on tabbar item to go to root view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191504/disable-action-user-taps-on-tabbar-item-to-go-to-root-view-controller/4192583#4192583)

Answer (score 3):

Though they say you're not supposed to subclass `UINavigationController`, you can what you want by making a subclass of `UINavigationController` and overriding the `- (NSArray *)popToRootViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated;` method.

Doing this (and not calling the super popToRootViewController) will prevent the view controllers from popping when you click the tab bar item. It could run you into some problems somehow, but hopefully it works for you.

Comment: Could you please tell me what is meaning of
- (NSArray *)popToRootViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated;
with passing as 'NO' in animated parameter.

Comment: @mjdth Do you by any chance know that trouble is not something "App getting rejected by Apple"? Otherwise it works like charm. Thanks for your tip.

Answer (score 3):

1. Include UITabBarControllerDelegate in your header file.
2. try this:

   ```
   - (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
     {
         if(bool_youDontWantPopToRootView)
              return (tabBarController.selectedViewController != viewController);
         return YES;
     }
   ```

For bool_youDontWantPopToRootView, you can add condition into it when you want it to behave like default behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

`- (NSArray *)popToRootViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated;`  when you pass 'NO' in animated argument you will be directed to root view without any animation

you  dont need to use this method while you tap on any tab bar its the default behaviour of the navigation controller that it maintain its own stack of VCs